# Django: static files not found

Tags: django

For some reason that I can not figure out. Only some of my static files are not loading. They used to but not anymore.

The ones loaded with `django-bower` work fine, any others don't.

Is it possible `django-bower` broke it or have I missed something.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'components')

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery#1.9',
    'knockout#3.3.0',
    'knockout-mapping#2.0',
    'bootstrap',
)
```

template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

project structure:

```
- project
  - apps
  - src
- static
    - css
        - styles.css
- media
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've replaced all staticfiles finders with only one, `BowerFinder`. This is no suprise that static files will be collected only from bower.

By default [`STATICFILES_FINDERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS) will contain:

```
(
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
```

If you still want to use that staticfiles finders, you must set them together with your `BowerFinder`.

Comment: Thank you. Don't know why but I completely overlooked that

Answer (score -4):

Try as:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/styles.css">
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.